# 16.04 64bit Chromium and Opera don't have flash

Tags: 16.04, flash

15.10 to 16.04 64bit Chromium and Opera don't have flash Firefox does. Every thing worked fine on 15.10 all of posts about this are two or four years old is there something current for 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Pepper Flash Plugin then restart your browser.

```
sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

Comment: I ran the command in your answer and restarted Opera.  It doesn't work.  It brings up the help center with the message: **Netflix system requirements for HTML5 Player and Silverlight**  Is there anything else that needs to be done to make it work?  My Ubuntu version is 16.04.  The Opera version is 44.0.2510.