# How do I install Silverlight on Opera browser on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, streaming, video-streaming

I still can't watch Netflix in Opera. I've tried following these guides, with no avail:

- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-enable-silverlight-watch-netflix-linux/
- [16.04 64bit Chromium and Opera don't have flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767731/16-04-64bit-chromium-and-opera-dont-have-flash)

I have no issue running Netflix etc. in Chrome, though.

Comment: 'with no avail' is not detailed enough for us to help you. Please edit your question with much more detail about exactly what you tried, and exactly how it failed. Is there some reason it *must* be Opera?

Comment: What exactly is the issue in opera?

Comment: @user535733 The user has already included in his question that he can watch Netflix using Chrome.  He's trying to watch Netflix using Opera.  I can watch Netflix in Chrome, Firefox, and Chromium.  However, it fails in Opera.  The error is a screen with an **Install Now** button to download Silverlight.  I'm also trying to figure out how to make Netflix work with Opera.  Does it work in your Ubuntu environment?  I'm trying to figure out how to make it work to give Netflix support to **Ubuntu 32 bit** users.

Answer (score 0):

As described in http://pipelight.net/ , we can view Netflix in HTML5 EME now.
I don't use Opera.
Does Opera support HTML5 EME ?
I used to enjoy other VOD contents (not Netflix) with Pipelight, but now they are available in native chromium (ver.56).

Comment: If you have questions about Opera it should be in the comments, to figure out the problem before providing an answer.  You can also install Opera and test what you think might be a workable answer.  What you posted as an answer doesn't sound as if you are certain about it.